# How do I do a Resharper structural search for this generic extension method?

Tags: c#, resharper, system.reactive

Can anyone guide me on creating a resharper structural search for the following signature:

```
namespace System
{
public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext);
}
```

I'm trying to detect the use of this overload of the rx subscribe function as it has no onError handler specified, which causes exceptions in bad places. As such I want to match on any specialisation of T.

I've tried a few options and can't seem to get it matching the specific instance types of this generic type. My attempts only match on generic methods that explicitly with IObservable rather than a specialisation such as IObservable.

I have for instance tried:

```
Subscribe(System.IObservable<$type$>, Action<$type$>)
```

where $type$ is just a type placeholder of no specific type.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you simply ask ReSharper to list usages of the method? Why do you have to do a "structural search" for it instead?

Comment: A structural search allows the creation of a resharper warning or error so that the team is alerted if they accidently use this pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible, so jetbrains have opened a ticket.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-409075

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to get any useful results from structured search for this. It's not great with generics.

I wondered if a regular expression search would prove useful. This found a lot of candidates for me:

```
\.Subscribe\([^,]*\)(?!,)
```

Which has the logic of looking for strings that start “.Subscribe(“ and then don’t have a comma until a “)” is found without a comma after it. It’s a bit convoluted, but seems to handle the case where the OnNext expression is non-trivial reasonably well. Use at your own risk as it obviously won't be perfect.

Also, don't forget about the Subscribe extension method for just `OnNext` and `OnCompleted` handlers.

EDIT

As mentioned in the OP comments, R#'s "Find usages" also works and probably better than this - but I couldn't get an equivalent in structured search to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
Subscribe($id0$, $id1$)
```

where you constrain, from a dropdown menu, $id0$ and $id1$ to be arguments of a specific type